# how to select this xml in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I need to select all guid node in the xml. but the code below only select the first one of them. how to do it?

```
DECLARE @doc XML

SET @doc = 
    '<ArrayOfGuid xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <guid>96eecbe2-d645-465d-8232-c7f21e3c6bf8</guid>
      <guid>38985702-0c0b-4e9c-bccb-af84ba4dd7ff</guid>
      <guid>67852205-092e-4db8-b31e-6f5d457db294</guid>
      <guid>92cf9106-445f-4b01-8259-613596b8a2a7</guid>
    </ArrayOfGuid>'

DECLARE @docHandle INT

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @docHandle OUTPUT,
     @doc

SELECT [guid]
FROM   OPENXML(@docHandle, '/ArrayOfGuid', 2)
       WITH
       ([guid] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
```

the result is just one row: 96EECBE2-D645-465D-8232-C7F21E3C6BF8

I need all 4 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably better ways to do this, but here's one of them:

```
SELECT text as guid
FROM   OPENXML(@docHandle, '//ArrayOfGuid/guid/text()', 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this approach using the native XQuery capabilities in SQL Server 2005 and newer:

```
SELECT
    Guids.value('(.)[1]', 'uniqueidentifier')
FROM 
    @doc.nodes('/ArrayOfGuid/guid') AS XTbl(Guids)
```

I always prefer this method over the older `OPENQUERY` approach